# How do i get the User Image from a lookup list on Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: json, ajax, sharepoint

I'm really stuck with getting the User image from a lookup list using AJAX with SharePoint 2013.

Ok so im getting my data from a Sp list called 'Comments', and im selecting a SP generated field called 'Created By' however on my SP its actually called 'Author'. This field only shows an ID so ive expanded it with OData to get the 'Author' details.

So what im trying to do is set up a custom comment section. So im taking data from the 'Author / Created By' column and outputting that on top of the persons comment. This all works fine!

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/DigiBlog/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Comments')/items?$select=Comment,Likes,BlogId,Created,Author/ID,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Id",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },

        success: function (data) {
          
          for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            var item = data.d.results[i];
            self.blogComments.push(item);
            //item.FirstName = item.FirstName.toLowerCase();
            //console.log(item);

          }
          console.log("Comment User Info Called");
        },

        error: function () {
          console.log("Comment User Info Error");
        }
      });
```

What i want is the picture Url from that user, so i can output an image of that person next to each comment. My Sharepoint is part of big organisation so theres a tonne of restrictions in place, one of which means i can't view the list of users so i can't see what fields i can actually use. Ive seen people use 'Picture' value in the select field, however when i try that the Ajax fails.

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/DigiBlog/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Comments')/items?$select=Comment,Likes,BlogId,Created,Author/ID,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Id",
```

All im looking for is the Author Img URl, ive tried Author/[Picture, PictureUrl, PictureUri, Image, ImageUri... and so on]. Ive spent 2 days on this and im not getting anywhere fast!

I either want a way to get the Picture Url or a way to show all the avaiable fields of 'Author' using console so i can find the relevant field i need to select.

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we could not get picture url directly.
[image]
Firstly,you could get user name.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Comments')/items(1)?$select=Owner/Name&$expand=Owner
```

Secondly,you could use this rest api to get picture url.

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'&$select=PictureUrl
```

The different versions of rest api versions are introduced [here](https://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2019/01/24/rest-api-sharepoint-get-user-information/).

**Tip**：The username obtained in the first step may need to be processed as in the example.